# How do I specify a constant attribute in XML Schema?

Tags: xml, xsd

Reading over the [XML Schema](http://www.w3.org/XML/Schema) specification, I can't see an easy way to mark an attribute as being constant (e.g. in `<foo bar="baz" />` the `bar` attribute must always be `baz`).  The only method I have come up with so far is to use an enumeration with only one element.  Is this the preferred method?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`<xs:attribute name="bar" type="xs:string" fixed="baz"/>` will make the attribute to have the value baz as constant.

Comment: I think you lost part of your answer.  What "will make the attribute to have the value baz as constant."

Comment: <xs:attribute name="bar" type="xs:string" fixed="baz"/>